# Passwordless ssh access to a remote machine using php?

Tags: php, bash, ssh, phpseclib

I use the below bash script to connect to a remote private machine using a pass-wordless ssh connect. I then run a set of commands on that machine.

I am trying to do exactly the same thing but run this on a web page using PHP. I am not sure were do i start from

I did try something in php but failed at it miserably not sure how do i do a password less ssh connection in php ?

```
ssh -t -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i ~/.ssh/iduser_rsa iduser@10.xxx.22.133 '

echo "hostname" > /tmp/iamhere.txt

cd /opt/im/olywc/bin/
echo "Checking server status:"
sudo ./status.sh
echo ""

ps -ef |grep -i main |grep -v grep
echo ""

echo "End of restart function"

exit
'
```

Converted the above to PHP code

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.xxx.22.133');
if (!$ssh->login('', '')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}


function printOutput($str)
{
    echo $str;
}

$ssh->exec('

echo "I am here" > /tmp/iamhere.txt
cd /opt/im/olywc/bin/
echo "Checking server status:"
sudo ./status.sh
echo ""

ps -ef |grep -i main |grep -v grep
echo ""

echo "End of restart function"

exit
'
, 'printOutput');

?>
```

Comment: Make sure you put a question in your question!

Comment: There is a question @Scopey, it is in the second paragraph.

Comment: I would recommend rewording the question so that it is quite obvious what you're asking. It seems to be more of a sentence ending in a question mark than an actual question. Nevertheless I think I get what you're asking and I have provided an answer below.

Comment: I hope that 10.105.22.133 is used for illustrative example, because it's still visible in your revisions.

Comment: Hi Bob that's right its a dummy id so no issues there :-)

Answer (score 1):

**phpseclib** (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) is a well maintained library for this. I've had a little experience using this library for key generation but it will allow you to create a simple SSH connection using any of the usual protocols and run commands through an SSH connection.

Check [this section](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using RSA key auth in your CLI version of the command. eg. `~/.ssh/iduser_rsa`. So try this:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('/home/user/.ssh/idusa_rsa'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.xxx.22.133');
if (!$ssh->login('', $rsa)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```